# OpenCV Face detect in stereo cameras

Tags: opencv, face-detection, stereo-3d, disparity-mapping

Here is what I am trying to do.

- Detect a person's face in 2 calibrated USB cameras individually.
- Get the coordinates of the face center in each camera.
- Calculate the corresponding point coordinates in disparity map.

With OpenCV sample code, I managed to

- Detect face and get the center coordinates in each camera.
- Calibrate 2 USB stereo cameras and get intrinsic and extrinsic parameter
- Get the disparity map from the stereo cameras

From here, how do I calculate the coordinates of the face in disparity map?

Thanks in advance,

Milo

Comment: Was there any progress on this project?